# Not getting the aggregated results I'm looking from Wikidata sparql query

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to get some data about Disneyland's hotels and I'm stuck here with architects. On of the hotels has two architects. As you can see I've tried to concatinate architects and group othe selected items.
But I'm not getting their labels instead I'm getting their URI. What am I missing?

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?hotel ?hotelLabel ?openingDateLabel ?countryLabel 
 (group_concat(?architects;separator=", ") as ?architect)
    WHERE 
   {  
?hotel wdt:P31    wd:Q27686;    # vi leder efter noget, som er "instance of" et hotel
       wdt:P361   wd:Q206521;   # og som er "part of" Disneyland Paris         
       wdt:P1619  ?openingDate;         
       wdt:P495   ?country;
       wdt:P84    ?architects.

SERVICE wikibase:label { 
  bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en".
  ?hotel rdfs:label ?hotelLabel .
  ?openingDate rdfs:label ?openingDateLabel .
  ?country rdfs:label ?countryLabel .
  ?architect rdfs:label ?architectLabel .
                       }
}
Group by ?hotel ?hotelLabel ?openingDateLabel ?countryLabel
```

[image: My results Look at architects..]

Comment: https://w.wiki/u9Q

Comment: Thanks man I apreiciate. Can you maybe take some time to explain what you did ? was it a typo?

Comment: 1. `(group_concat(?architectLabel;separator=", ") as ?architect)`,
2. `?architects rdfs:label ?architectLabel`.